# parallelize an oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

My request sounds like this: Display sellers and buyers in your city with a rating of more than 100.

```
SELECT *
FROM Sal outer 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Cust inner WHERE outer.snum = inner.snum AND rating > 100);
```

But according to the task I need to parallelize it, tell me how to do it? I tried this option, but it doesn't work

```
SELECT /*+ FULL(hr_emp) PARALLEL(hr_emp, 2) */ SNUM
FROM Sal outer hr_emp;
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Cust inner WHERE outer.snum = inner.snum AND rating > 100);
```

contents of the CUST table:
[image]

contents of the SAL table:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Parallel](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/hintsref.htm#CHDJIGDG) hint is described in documentation.

- it looks as if you copy/pasted some code from who-knows-where, hoping it'll automagically work
- `full (hr_emp)` hint? Where did `hr_emp` come from and what does it have to do with your case?
- `outer`? Sounds like `outer join`, but you used it as a table alias in the 1st `select` you posted, while its usage in the 2nd is completely invalid.

It would probably help if you posted sample data (`create table` and `insert into` statements) as well as desired output, as it is quite difficult to guess what you really have.

---

After you edited the question, then your query might look like this:

```
select /*+ parallel (2) */
  c.cnum, c.cname, c.rating, s.sname
from cust c join sal s on s.snum = c.snum
where c.rating > 100;
```

Comment: I understand that it is necessary to use an instruction to the optimizer to
execute the query in parallel in the implemented command. But I don't understand how to do it. hr_emp found in the documentation

Comment: I edited the answer; have a look, please.